# Can not define an array of structure in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, structure

I defined `ball` structure in this way:

```
struct ball
{
 _vector coordinates;
 _vector velocity;
 _vector acceleration;

 int border;
 int color;
 int radius;

 float mass;

 void step();
 void clear();
 void render();
};
```

(data type `_vector` is defined before and it represents the vector in mathematics)

in the main function i wanted to define an array of `ball`s so i wrote this code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct ball balls[NO_BALLS];
.
.
.
}
```

but when i wanna compile the code i get this error:

> no matching function for call to `ball::ball()' candidates are:
>   ball::ball(const ball&)

Comment: Your error complains about the fact that you don't have an argument-less constructor for your struct (and that you defined the copy constructor). Is the code you pasted the current version?

Comment: Does `_vector` have `_vector()` constructor defined?

Comment: Great name choices for your variable and constant.

Comment: There was an extra line in my code here `ball(const ball&)` that is not in the main code, sorry.

Comment: But the extra line that isn't there is still part of the error message...

Comment: It works perfectly now :) thanks to everybody

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you define the copy constructor `ball::ball(const ball&)` (which you've actually commented out in your code), there will be no compiler generated defaulted default constructor. There needs to be a default constructor for your array definition to work (because it default initializes each of the elements). So simply provide a default constructor: `ball:ball() { }`. You will probably want to initialize your member variables in this constructor.

Comment: +1:  This is the problem, the fact that the code posted in the OP doesn't match the error notwithstanding.

Comment: Thanks so much!! i don't know what happened this time and this code worked, because i tried defining an empty constructor before but it didn't fixed the problem!!